# Does anyone know how to set datalayer in functions.php for fusion form (Avada) completion which will send e-mail and phone number to google analytics

Tags: html, wordpress, google-analytics, wordpress-shortcode

How to formulate data layer below which will dynamically fill e-mail and phone number when user submits avada fusion form in console on datalayer command?

`<script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; window.dataLayer.push({  'event': 'form_completion',  'email': 'test@test.nl',  'phone_number': '31612345678'  }); </script>`

Thanks,

Data layer form completion should show dynamically filled data.